# When packing disks into a square, is it best to be greedy?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, packing-problem

The problem is to pack $n$ non-overlapping disks (not necessarily of the same size) of greatest total area  into a unit square. The case $n=1$ is obvious: just place a disk of radius $\frac12$ centrally in the square, to occupy an area $\frac14\pi\approx78.54\%$ of the square. For $n=2$, we can do no better than follow up the previous case and add a disk (of radius $\frac32-\surd2$) in a corner to touch the existing disk and two sides of the square, thus altogether covering an area $(\frac92-3\surd2)\pi\approx80.85\%$ of the square. Similarly, for $n=3,4,5$, we can do no better than place further disks of that size in the remaining corners of the square.

For $n=6,...,13$, it seems optimal to build on the case $n=5$ and place further disks in the eight regions bounded by a side of the square, the disk of radius $\frac12$, and a disk of radius $\frac32-\surd2$. Clearly, we can keep going like this, packing the next disk into whatever remaining space will accommodate the largest disk—the greedy method. But the question arises:

**Is there an $n$ for which the packing of maximal total area is not the greedy packing described above?**

Comment: For $n=1, 4, 16, 64. . .  2^{2(n-1)}$ total area is constant. The neasure of radii of circles between each four circle reduces with increasing n. So I think maximal total area is  for n=1 plus some more circles in four corners. finally if you want circles with same diameter n must be a member of above sequence.

Comment: @Sil : If your comment were posted as an answer, it would probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: @JohnBentin Okay turned it into one, although probably not satisfying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an open problem according to the [On Malfatti’s Marble Problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40598-016-0047-5) article from 2016:

> Conjecture 3: For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \geq 3$, the greedy arrangement solves the problem of finding an arrangement of $n$ circles in a tangential $k$-gon with the maximal total area.